# Join clause in delete query with squirrel/PostgreSQL

Tags: go, squirrel

I'm using the squirrel (`github.com/Masterminds/squirrel`) statement builder tool and Postgres DB.

`Vendor` and `Vendor_Location` are the two tables we have.
Both tables are linked by the `vendor_no` attribute.

I need to delete information from Vendor Location that is no longer active. I need to delete data from location by joining them together; this can be done with the following SQL:

```sql
DELETE FROM vendor_location vl
        USING vendor v
    WHERE vl.vendor_no=v.vendor_no and v.last_login_date >= 'date';
```

Delete statement builder doesn't has a join function so I have implemented the query as:

```go
squirrel.Delete("vendor_location vl").
Suffix("USING vendor v WHERE vl.vendor_no=v.vendor_no and v.last_login_date >= $1", date)
```

Please let me know if there is another option by using the same query builder tool.

Comment: There are a few open issues on the repo regarding this ( [125](https://github.com/Masterminds/squirrel/issues/125), [257](https://github.com/Masterminds/squirrel/issues/257), [PR 295](https://github.com/Masterminds/squirrel/pull/295) ).